# how to convert a CSV into JSON using Python Or Java. The csv is representation of a nested JSON (Containing array of json objects and nested objects)

Tags: java, python, json, csv

I get a csv file like :

attrib1_x , attrib1_y , attrib1_z_0_p , attrib1_z_0_c , attrib1_z_1_p , attrib1_z_1_c , attrib2_R , attrib2_K , attrib3

1 , 2 , 100 , 200 , 500 , 600 , 222 , 320 ,hello

---

The csv represents a json like below.

---

```
{
"attrib1":{
           "x":1,
           "y":2,
           "z":[{"p":100,"c":200},{"p":500,"c":600}]
          },
"attrib2":{"R":222,"K":320},
"attrib3":"hello"
}
```

---

### So basically here I get the above CSV, and need to convert it to the JSON structure shown

. Not sure how to do it. is there any library(Python/Java) which can help me with this.

If any solution/suggestion with different csv header available that will also work. i can ask the team to provide me the csv with different header names to represent the nested / arrays.

Comment: Do you know the structure of the object you want to build or do you need to extract that from the headers? In any case I don't think there is a library for it, but it should be easy to build each object parsing the file line by line.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{
"attrib1":{
           "x":1,
           "y":2,
           "z":[{"p":100,"c":200},{"p":500,"c":600}]
          },
"attrib2":{"R":222,"K":320},
"attrib3":"hello"
}");
```

Just try and out.
It may help

Comment: #in python   myDct={ "attrib1":{ "x":1, "y":2, "z":[{"p":100,"c":200},{"p":500,"c":600}] }, "attrib2":{"R":222,"K":320}, "attrib3":"hello" }
for key,value in myDct.items():
    print(key,value)

Answer (score 1):

First you iterate the `key` Then similarly iterate `value` and save into csv

```
  String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                try(Writer writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\m.hussain\\Desktop\\CSV\\testing.csv"))
                {
                    for (Map<String, Object> map : objectRecords)
                    {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
                        {
                            writer.append(entry.getKey())
                                    .append(',');
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    writer.append(eol);
                    for (Map<String, Object> map : objectRecords)
                    {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                            try
                            {
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                                writer.append(jsonObject.getString("value"));
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                writer.append(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                            }
                            writer.append(',');
                        }
                        writer.append(eol);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row of your CSV contains field names (which uses the underline to show the hierarchical relationship) and detail data starts from the second line, and you need to transform the CSV to JSON format. Here the difficulty is dynamic parsing. It will involve grouping, recursion, loop, conditional judgment and string concatenation. The code will be rather lengthy if you try to do this in Java.

Try using SPL, the open-source Java package, to do this. It is easy and five lines of code are enough:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2inE.png)

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as recurse.splx and invoke it in a Java application as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call recurse()");
st.execute();
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Use library *Josson* to build the JSON structure.

First, split the csv file header and content, and build a Map. Then use function `unflatten()` to do transformation.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> csv = new LinkedHashMap<>();
csv.put("attrib1_x", 1);
csv.put("attrib1_y", 2);
csv.put("attrib1_z_0_p", 100);
csv.put("attrib1_z_0_c", 200);
csv.put("attrib1_z_1_p", 500);
csv.put("attrib1_z_1_c", 600);
csv.put("attrib2_R", 222);
csv.put("attrib2_K", 320);
csv.put("attrib3", "hello");

Josson josson = Josson.from(csv);
System.out.println(josson.getNode().toPrettyString()); // before unflatten

JsonNode node = josson.getNode("unflatten('_')");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString()); // after unflatten
```

Output: before unflatten

```
{
  "attrib1_x" : 1,
  "attrib1_y" : 2,
  "attrib1_z_0_p" : 100,
  "attrib1_z_0_c" : 200,
  "attrib1_z_1_p" : 500,
  "attrib1_z_1_c" : 600,
  "attrib2_R" : 222,
  "attrib2_K" : 320,
  "attrib3" : "hello"
}
```

Output: after unflatten

```
{
  "attrib1" : {
    "x" : 1,
    "y" : 2,
    "z" : [ {
      "p" : 100,
      "c" : 200
    }, {
      "p" : 500,
      "c" : 600
    } ]
  },
  "attrib2" : {
    "R" : 222,
    "K" : 320
  },
  "attrib3" : "hello"
}
```